# LINQ Room id where user exists

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I have two tables:

**ChatRoom**

- Id (int)

**ChatUser** (where i insert the users to the chat room, 1 row per user)

- RoomId (int) // Id from table ChatRoom
- UserId (int)

I want to loop out all rooms where im in i do like this.

```
ChatUserDTO chatUser = db.ChatUser.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

But how do get the room id where the second user with the variable userId2 exists?
If there are no rooms where both user exists it should return RoomId = 0.

Got it to work with this code but there must be a better way to do it.

```
var chatExists = (from cu in db.ChatUser
                 where cu.UserId == userId    
                 select new { cu.RoomId })
                 .ToList();

var chatRoomId = 0;

foreach (var item in chatExists)
{
    ChatUserDTO checkRoom = 
            db.ChatUser.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.UserId == userId2 && x.RoomId == item.RoomId);

    if (checkRoom != null)
        chatRoomId = checkRoom.RoomId;
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault won't loop out all the rooms, it will just return the first one. If you want all the rooms, then you should do a Where instead.

Comment: changed it and added code that do what i want but there must be a more optimized way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could intersect the two sets of rooms, this gives you more information than you requested:

```
var rooms1 = db.ChatUser.Where(cu => cu.UserId == userId).Select(cu => cu.RoomId);
var rooms2 = db.ChatUser.Where(cu => cu.UserId == userId2).Select(cu => cu.RoomId);

var roomsWithBoth = rooms1.Intersect(rooms2);
```

Another alternative would be to use `GroupBy` to group the ChatUser records by room and then find rooms that contain both userIds. This approach might be better if, say, you have N different users and are looking for a common room.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Ling to SQL JOIN` then use Lambda expression to sort out what you are looking for from that `query`.

It would look something like this:

```
var rooms = (from cu in db.ChatUser
            join cr in db.ChatUser on cu.Id equals cr.UserId
            select cu).ToList();
//Now Sort 
var rooms = rooms.Where(x => x.UserId.equals(userId) && x.UserId !=null ).Select(x => RoomId).FirstorDefault();
```

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for. Perhaps it can lead you down the road to figuring out how to refactor your code, and make it look neater.